# stop actionCable after fewDays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, thin, systemctl, faye

```
Hi everybody,
I want to use binance websocket and show in view with ActionCable.
I created file  `lib/ticker.rb` as below:
```

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'json'

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

EM.run do
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=ethusdt@ticker/btcusdt@ticker")
  ws.on :message do |event|
    response = JSON.parse(event.data)
    if response['stream'].split("@")[1] == 'ticker' && response['data']['s'][-4..-1] == 'USDT')
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'ticker_channel', stream: response['stream'], content: response['data']
    end
  end
end
```

```
Then I created systemctl to run it as below:
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Thin Binance Ticker
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/nginx/html/myproject
ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/wrappers/bundle exec thin start -R lib/ticker.rb -p 9292
User=root
Group=root

RestartSec=1
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
But after a few days of starting it, the ActionCable does not work but the systemctl status is active!
I have to restart the systemctl manually, to work ActionCable again.
Anyone have an idea?
```

Comment: Where are you running this - local machine, server, cloud? For example, do things work properly locally but have problems after you deploy to the cloud?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use a vps.